# OMS agent failure 12019

Tags: azure

I have troubles to connect the OMS (Operation Management Suite) agent to Azure. It reports "The agent had an unkonown failure 12019". I am sure that is a network issue, but I'm not able to detect the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit later but may help someone else.

In my case, it only was a conectivity problem because the computer was reporting to OMS through a OMS proxy in a second computer and the proxy service in this computer had been disabled.

Reporting directly fixed it. Enabling the service or using another proxy had the same effect.

Best regards.